# Check if all characters in an array are integers

Tags: c, arrays, user-input

I'm working on my first simple C program in Visual Studios 2017. The goal is to get two user inputs which have to be integers.

I go through the array and check if every character is an integer but it still returns "The input is not a valid number". Also after retrying 3 times the console crashes.

"projectExample.exe has triggered a breakpoint. occurred" is the displayed message.

```
int main()
{
    char userInputM[10];
    char userInputN[10];

    //get the value of M from the user
    printf("Enter a value for M: ");
    fgets(userInputM, sizeof(userInputM), stdin);
    //printf(userInputM);

    //check that the entered value for M is a valid positive number
    const int lenOfInput1 = strlen(userInputM);
    for (int i = 0; lenOfInput1; i++) {

        if (!isdigit(userInputM[i])) {
            printf("The input is not a valid number. Try again");

            printf("Enter a value for M: ");
            fgets(userInputM, sizeof(userInputM), stdin);
            printf(userInputM);
        }
    }

    //check that the entered value for N is a number 

    //convert the user input for M to an int for calculation
    //int factorM = atoi(userInputM);
    //printf("%d", factorM);

    //int result = calculate();
    //int a;
    //scanf("%d", &a);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that `fgets()` will include the newline, and newline is not a digit. Also, don't forget that recalcitrant users might type some blanks or tabs before and/or after the number. You might want to allow that as valid, but not if there are spaces in the number. Inside your loop, you need to re-measure the length of the input after getting more data — you need a `lenOfInput1 = strlen(userInputM);` after the embedded `fgets()`. The loop condition `for (int i = 0; lenOfInput1; i++)` should probably be `for (int i = 0; i < lenOfInput1; i++)` — or you might need to subtract one for `\n`.

Comment: `size_t len; if (!fgets(userInputM, sizeof(userInputM), stdin)) {/*handle error*/} len = strlen(userInputM); if (len && userInputM[len-1] == '\n') userInputM[--len] = 0;` (don't forget `#include <string.h>` and do the same for both inputs)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make sure that the number is an integer, you could read in the input into an `int` with `scanf()` and check the return value.

```
int M, rv=-1;
while(rv!=1)
{
    if(rv==0)
    {
        getchar();
    }
    rv=scanf("%d", &M);
}
```

[`scanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) would return the number of variables to which values were assigned successfully which will be `1` if the above `scanf()` is successful.

If the input was not a number and hence the `scanf()` returns `0`, the entered value, which is not a number, is still left unconsumed in the input buffer and that needs to be consumed. It could be done with a `getchar()`.
Otherwise, `scanf()` will keep trying to read the same value and `rv` will be `0` each time.

In this way, you don't need a string buffer or a need to use `atoi()`.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39119000/distinguish-between-a-letter-and-integer-in-c) as well.

---

As pointed out in the comments, `fgets()` will read in the trailing new line (`\n`) into the string and `\n` is not a digit.

You could replace the `\n` with `\0` like

```
str[strlen(str)-1]='\0';
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid using scanf() because Visual Studios complaints that its not safe but I'll change the preprocessor definition and try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;
int i = 0;
while (userInputM[i])
{
    if (userInputM[i] >= '0' && userInputM[i] <= '9') //if it's an integer
     {
        ++count;  //do something like creating new array and put the
                  //data inside or in my case I count the # of ints
        ++i;
      }    
    else
        ++i;
}
```