# How to make a program repeat a set amount of times?

Tags: c, gcc

So, I have a Program which checks if a Triangle is valid, here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main()  
{  
    int side1, side2, side3; 

    /* Initially assume that the triangle is not valid */
    int valid = 0;

    /* Input all three sides of a triangle */  
    printf("Enter three sides of triangle: \n");  
    scanf("%d%d%d", &side1, &side2, &side3);  

    if((side1 + side2) > side3)  
    {  
        if((side2 + side3) > side1)  
        {  
            if((side1 + side3) > side2)
            {  
                /*
                 * If side1 + side2 > side3 and
                 *    side2 + side3 > side1 and
                 *    side1 + side3 > side2 then
                 * the triangle is valid. Hence set
                 * valid variable to 1.
                 */
                valid = 1;
            }  
        }
    }  

    /* Check valid flag variable */
    if(valid == 1)
    {
        printf("Triangle is valid.");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Triangle is not valid.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But what I want to do is add a Prompt to ask how many triangles to check, so I would add something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main()  
{  
    int repeats; 

    /* Input the amount of repeats  */  
    printf(" the amount of repeats: \n");  
    scanf("%", &repeats);
...
```

The amount of entered should be the amount of triangles the user wants to check.

Bonus Question: How to check that the user entered only a number and no letter.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the return value of [`scanf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) .. you'll also want to double check your format specifier.

Answer (score 1):

The

```
scanf("%", &repeats);
```

must've been

```
scanf("%d", &repeats);
```

as `repeats` is an `int`.

You could just place the block of code that you want to execute repeatedly in a loop like

```
for(i=0; i<repeats; ++i)
{
    //your code
}
```

To check whether the user entered a number and not a character check the return value of `scanf()`. It returns the number of successful assignments it did.

Since the format specifier is `%d` in

```
scanf("%d", &repeats);
```

`scanf()` expects an integer. But if a character was given out instead, it won't assign (and would return `0` in this case)  and the input (which is not a number) will remain unconsumed in the input buffer.

```
if( scanf("%d", &repeats)!=1 )
{
    //value was not read into 'repeats'
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39119000/distinguish-between-a-letter-and-integer-in-c) might be of interest to you.

Now if the invalid input remains in the input buffer, it can cause problems with the next `scanf()`. So it must somehow be consumed.

You could do something like

```
int ch;
while( (ch=getchar())!='\n' && ch!=EOF );
```

This would consume from the input buffer till the next new line (`\n`).

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c).

And your

```
if((side1 + side2) > side3)  
{  
    if((side2 + side3) > side1)  
    {  
        if((side1 + side3) > side2)
        {  
            valid = 1;
        }  
    }
}
```

could be made

```
if( (side1 + side2)>side3 && (side2 + side3)>side1 &&  (side1+side3)>side2 )
{  
    valid = 1;
}
```

and you don't really need the extra parenthesis because arithmetic operators have greater precedence than relational operators which in turn have greater precedence than logical operators.

Look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Answer (score 0):

you could achieve that simply by wrapping a do while around your code so that it looks something like that

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main()  
{  
    int repeats = 0, counter = 0; 

    /* Input the amount of repeats  */  
    printf(" the amount of repeats: \n");  
    scanf("%d", &repeats);

    do {
     ...
     check here if its a triangle
     ...
     counter++;

    } while(counter < repeats);
```